# Add Prototype Function to ngResource in Angular Factory method

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to add a prototypal function to my ngResource factory method like this:

```
 .factory('Magazine', function ($resource) {

var Magazine = $resource('http://localhost/dooleystand/ci/api/magazine/:magId', {
  loginID : organEntity,
  password : organCommpassword,
  magId : "@magId"
});

Magazine.prototype.getLastAdded = function() {
  return this.get({magId:"lastAdded"});
};

return Magazine;

})
```

Then I tried to call this factory method from a function in my controller:

```
Magazine.save(magazine, function() {

    var newMagazine = Magazine.getLastAdded;

    var tempMagazine = {
            issue_number : newMagazine.issue_number,
        magazine_name : newMagazine.magazine_name
    };
    $scope.magazines.push(tempMagazine);
    });
```

It seems like my browser did not generate a new request at all. Any way to actually accomplish this or do I need to have a separate factory method?

Comment: 1st fix your `var newMagazine = Magazine.getLastAdded();` - brackets.

Comment: @Nenad Yeah...I did that before this post. I got an error: `TypeError: Object function e(c){z(c||{},this)} has no method 'getLastAdded'`

Comment: I may be wrong, but doesn't extended prototype only affect objects constructed by Magazine, rather than Magazine itself? ie. You're calling `Magazine.getLastAdded()` rather that `new Magazine().getLastAdded()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about extend the resource actions like this?

```
.factory('Magazine', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('http://localhost/dooleystand/ci/api/magazine/:magId', {
        loginID: organEntity,
        password: organCommpassword,
        magId: "@magId"
    }, {
        getLastAdded: { method: 'GET', params: { magId: 'lastAdded' } }
    });
}
```

Comment: Yeah! It does solve my problem..I just wonder about that prototypical function...thanks anyway!

Comment: You can only access .prototype through the constructor function of Object, i think... and that's not in your scope. It's inside angular-resource.js and closed in a function scope.